# Fiat uno mia 1.1

Tags: engine

I am trying to set the distributor on my uno , the mark i made prior to removing it does not line up anymore and I am not able to turn the camshaft for some reason, I tried turning the motor by hand at the crankshaft , but the the cam and it's belt is not turning.

Answer (score 2):

Before trying to set the timing on your distributor, you have to make sure that the crank and cam are correctly timed to each other.  This is usually done by setting piston number 1 to Top Dead Centre (TDC) which is the point where the crown of the piston is at the top of the bore.  You then set the camshaft to the point at which the inlet and exhaust vales on cylinder one are both closed.  It isn't quite as simple as this though as the valves will typically open and close at prescribed points.

There should be marking somewhere on your crank pulley and cam wheel that you can use to time these up.  Once this is done you can tension the timing belt and turn the engine by hand a couple of times to make sure it comes back to TDC with no contact internally and that the timing marks still line up.

Only once this is complete should you attempt to line up your distributor ignition timing.  If you are turning the crank and the cam isn't turning.  Something is fundamentally wrong with your timing gear.

Depending on the age and type of engine fitted, you may find the following link contains some helpful information for you.

[Fiat Forum FIRE engine timing marks](http://www.fiatforum.com/punto-ii/19733-photos-timing-marks-8v-f-i-r-e-engines.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have removed a timing belt/chain and lost a cam timing, Try this: Get your crank shaft about 90° after or before TDC, so your pistons are about the same level. Then try to turn the cam shaft over. Because if you do it at TDC, your valves will hit the piston, which will stop your cam shaft turning.

---

If you haven't taken belt/chain off, it must be trapped cam shaft when fitted a distributor. Take the distributor off, and try to turn over. If it turns over, fit the distributor back on, make sure the distributors shaft perfectly fits in camshaft end, don't worry about ignition timing. When you're done, try to turn over again. If it turns, adjust the ignition timing (to your marks), and tighten the bolts. And try to turn over again. If it don't turn, tell us at what point it stops turning over.